# Load wordpress page with AJAX and resolve theme shortcodes

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am currently creating a wordpress page based on the [X Theme](https://theme.co/x/) which utilises [Cornerstone](https://theme.co/cornerstone/) as a page builder.

I am trying to dynamically load pages into the main page with AJAX. For this I created a script making a request to `admin-ajax.php` which works flawlessly.

Now the tricky part: I added a PHP snippet with the plugin [Code Snippets](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) containing the following code:

```
function get_case() {
    global $wpdb;

    $postNo = intval( $_POST['case'] );

    $post = get_post($postID);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
    $html = do_shortcode($content)
    echo $html;

    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_case', 'get_case' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_case', 'get_case' );
```

This code returns correct results if I am using the wordpress page builder, however it simply returns the shortcodes of the theme if the page was built in Cornerstone.

e.g.

```
[cs_element_section _id=”1″][cs_element_row _id=”2″]...
```

Am I doing this correctly? Shouldn't do_shortcodes() resolve those shortcodes? Is there any other way to dynamically load sub pages?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is better to use WP_Query() and the_content() in the famous Wordpress template [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need `do_shortcode` (or `global $wpdb` if this is your full code) because that is run automatically on *the_content* assuming it wasn't unhooked elsewhere. We can't see your full set-up (plugins, theme, custom code) to fully debug, but this code below is all you would need on a Plain Vanilla WordPress site to accomplish what you're trying to do. If this doesn't work, the problem is elsewhere in your set-up:

```
function get_case() {
  $postNo = intval( $_POST['case'] );
  $post = get_post($postNo); // NOTE: Your code has the wrong variable here
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
  exit( $content );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_case', 'get_case' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_case', 'get_case' );
```